# Puedo obtener el nombre el skin seleccionado devexpress?

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

```
Private Sub Principal_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    DevExpress.UserSkins.BonusSkins.register()
    SkinHelper.InitSkinPopupMenu(SeleccionaSkin)
End Sub
```

hasta aquí bien, aplica el skin de manera normal, no se si usando este metodo pueda obtener el nombre del skin seleccionado, esto con el fin de guardar el ultimo y aplicarlo al iniciar nuevamente el programa.

SeleccionaSkin es un SkinBarSubItem

Answer (score 1):

Puedes obtener el skin actual con:

```
Dim skinActual As String = UserLookAndFeel.Default.SkinName
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola que tal Yo uso el Componente 
**SkinRibbonGalleryBarItem** ese lo lleno ligando un **StyleManager** y **DefaultLookAndFeel**

y en el Evento de Gallery : **GalleryItemClick** en su atributo **e.Item.Tag** viene el nombre exacto de el Skin que se selecciona, lo guardo en una variable de aplicación o no se bien como se les llama, de esta manera:

```
Dim style As String
style = e.Item.Tag

style = Replace(style, "(", "")
style = Replace(style, ")", "")

My.Settings.StyleForm = style
My.Settings.Save()
```

y para aplicarla en el **Load** como tu, hice esto:

```
Dim style As String
 style = My.Settings.StyleForm
 UserLookAndFeel.Default.SetSkinStyle(style)
 DefaultLookAndFeel1.LookAndFeel.ActiveLookAndFeel.SetSkinStyle(style)
```

espero te ayude Saludos.